# how can i get input text value and pass in button onclick method in javascript function pass by values

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function addData (n1, n2) {
    alert(fn+ln);
}
```

```html
 <body>
   <input Type="text" name="n1">
   <input Type="text" name="n2">
   <button onClick="addData(n1.value,n2.value)">click</button> 
</body>
```

its give me the following error:

> ReferenceError: n1 is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this way:

```js
function addData (e) {
var rec = 0;
var t = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++){
rec=rec+parseInt(t[i].value);
}
console.log(rec);
}
```

```html
<script>
   
</script>

<body>
    <input Type="text" name="n1">
    <input Type="text" name="n2">
    <button onClick="addData(this)">click</button> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the value of the input by using `n1.value` You need to obtain the DOM element using `document.getElementById` and use its value to obtain the string value and parse it as `Integer` before you add them.

See this:

```js
function addData (n1, n2) {
    n1Val = parseInt(n1.value);
    n2Val = parseInt(n2.value);
    alert(n1Val+n2Val);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input Type="text" id="n1">
    <input Type="text" id="n2">
    <button onClick="addData(document.getElementById('n1'), document.getElementById('n2'))">click</button> 
</body>
```

If you want to merely concatenate the data and not add it, just remove the `parseInt` call and add the strings like in the following example:

```js
function addData (n1, n2) {
 n1Val = n1.value;
    n2Val = n2.value;
    alert(n1Val+n2Val);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input Type="text" id="n1">
    <input Type="text" id="n2">
    <button onClick="addData(document.getElementById('n1'), document.getElementById('n2'))">click</button>  
</body>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: tnks varun, but my input field name not fix thats why i need to pass value in html page.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Input tutorial</title>
        <script language="javascript">
            function addNumbers()
            {
                var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
                var final = val1 + val2;
                alert(final);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
     
    <body>
        value1 = <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="1" /> value2 = <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="2" />
        <input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()" /> 
    </body> 

</html>
```